# counting the number of letter occurences in an Array

Tags: c, arrays

I want a code that counts the number of occurrences of letters in an array. I have looked at various codes that do the exact, but they all use strings. My issue here is to **strictly use arrays**. 
I have created a code, but it returns: `: 0 : 1 : 2 : 3 : 4 : 5 : 6 : 7 : ...`

one correct example: 
**input**:

```
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
```

**output**:

```
A: 1
B: 1
C: 1
D: 1
E: 3
F: 1 ...
```

The following is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
int main(void)
{
    int i = 0;
    int c;
    char counts[26] = {0};  

    c = getchar();              


    while (c != EOF && i < 26) {
        counts[i] = c;
        i += 1;
        c = getchar();           
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 26; i++) {

        if (counts[i] !=0 ) 
        printf("%c: %d", toupper(c), i);
    }


    return EXIT_SUCCESS;

}
```

Comment: Where do you think you wrote the code that counts the amount of each char?....

Comment: Big plus for providing example input with expected output! It's not popular nowadays :p

Comment: +1 for that, and for testing for eof correctly. Many even more experienced programmers do not understand and use it properly. Makes me confident you'll figure out the counting and stuff as well ;-).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using your code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
int main(void)
{
    int c;
    int counts['Z' - 'A'] = {0};
    c = getchar();
    while (c != EOF) 
    {
         if (isalpha(c))
            counts[(toupper(c)-'A')]++;
         c = getchar();
    }

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < sizeof(counts)/sizeof(counts[0]); i++) 
    {    
        if (counts[i] !=0 )
            printf("%c: %d\n", 'A'+i, counts[i]);
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

1. Your array is designed to store occurencies of each letter. So the idex of an array must be the latter entered. As you can see I used `(toupper(c)-'A')` that makes the value of entered char 0 based index.
2. You must check that entered char is an alphabet char. `if (isalpha(c))` do that.
3. The printout must print characters using the index of array and array content

Comment: You don't need to initialize `int i =0;` since `for` loop is starting from `i=0` .

Comment: @kvk30 Weel, hope this is not the cause of downvote ;) BTW not an error/problem. It was pasted form the OP code, but I used to do anyway that to avoid future bugs with local scoped vars.

Comment: @LPs Ur code works just fine, except that it only returns a maximum of 18 letters. so testing the code with the example above, it returns the letters from I to Z, and misses out on the letters from A to H.

Comment: @Moh'dH The code works fine. Take a look at [this online service](http://ideone.com/PTEcMU)

Comment: @LPs My bad, it was an issue with the view window. Ur answer has been accepted.

Comment: I see no downvote, but as I'm sure you're aware, magic numbers are typically frowned upon, and in this case the magic number here could cause problems on systems using EBCDIC character sets; to make this a *superb* answer you might want to change `int counts[26] = {0};` to `int counts['Z' - 'A'] = {0};`. P.S. Happy "nice answer" badge day ;)